# Elements of the jumbotron is not properly aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day! I'm having a struggle to aligned the jumbtron to my calendar icon. And the elements of the jumbtron is not inside of it. Can someone help me how to solve this? Ideas? i just started studying bootstrap and css.

Here's the picture.

[image]

here is my html code.

```
 <div class="events">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class= "col-sm-4 col-xs-25">
         <h4 id="event"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upcoming Events</h4>
         <hr class="carved">
         <div class="date">
           <span class="month">August</span>
           <h1 class="day">28</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="container">
           <div class="jumbotron">
             <h4>Sample Title</h4>
             <p>IT Thesis defense</p>
             <h6>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</h6>
           </div>
         </div>
         <hr class="divider">
         <div class="date">
           <span class="month">August</span>
           <h1 class="day">28</h1>
         </div>
         <hr class="divider">
         <div class="date">
           <span class="month">August</span>
           <h1 class="day">28</h1>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class= "col-sm-8 col-xs-25">
         <h4 id="event"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Latest News</h4>
         <hr class="carved">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

here is my css

```
#event {
  color: #a92419;
}
hr.carved {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      color-stop(0.5, rgb(126,27,18)),
      color-stop(0.5, rgb(211,45,31))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
      center top,
      rgb(126,27,18) 50%,
      rgb(211,45,31) 50%
  );
}
.date {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}
.date .month {
  background: #a92419;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a92419;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #a92419;
}

.date .day {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#a92419;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.date .day::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 95%;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
}

.date .day::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.jumbotron {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:none;
}
.jumbotron p {
  font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: not an answer - but a comment - I like the way you have your calendar dates styled. Very nice!

Comment: @gavgrif thanks but i just recycle it. i see it in cssdecks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.container`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) class carries its own width(s) and is intended to be used as a outer wrapper for your layout.  Because of this, they do not tend to nest well. The one you have as a sibling of your `.date` classed elements is breaking the layout.

As for the spacing of the `.jumbotron` contents, Bootstrap assigns some pretty dramatic padding to that class by default. Consider overwriting that with your own values in your `.jumbotron` rule. The other issue — the `.jumbotron` contents bleeding out of their container — that is a result of the `height: 100px` you are setting. You can stop the contents from taking up space beyond the boundaries of the `.jumbotron` by adding/modifying its [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property. *This may be a matter of opinion but I think it is usually better to avoid setting `height` in the CSS and let the contents define the size of the container — especially in cases where the content is CMS/client driven.*

If you remove the `.container`, you’ll still have the problem of the `.date` and `.jumbotron` stacking vertically. To address that, you might consider treating Date element as `.row` with a column for your `.date` element, and a column for that Date’s event(s).

```
<hr class="carved">

<div class=“row”><!-- the Date wrapper -->

  <div class="col-sm-4">

    <div class="date">
      <span class="month">August</span>
      <h1 class="day">28</h1>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8"><!-- this column holds all the Events for this Date -->

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h4>Sample Title</h4>
        <p>IT Thesis defense</p>
        <h6>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</h6>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** The new structure will require a bit of adjustment to some of your CSS `width` properties, and the `col-` device/sizes I put on the Date and Event columns are just examples — size as needed.

Comment: Thanks bro it worked. I just need adjust the size of the text, links inside of it. and remove the margin.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2">
         <h4 id="event"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upcoming Events</h4>
         <hr class="carved">
        <div class="date">
        <span class="month">August</span>
        <h1 class="day">28</h1>
    </div><!-- date -->
</div><!-- md2 --> 

<div class="col-md-10">
<h4 id="event"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Latest News</h4>
<hr class="carved">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h4>Sample Title</h4>
    <p>IT Thesis defense</p>
    <h6>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</h6>
    </div><!-- jumbo -->
</div><!-- md10 -->

</div><!-row>
</div><!-- container -->
```

+

```
#event {
  color: #a92419;
}
hr.carved {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      color-stop(0.5, rgb(126,27,18)),
      color-stop(0.5, rgb(211,45,31))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
      center top,
      rgb(126,27,18) 50%,
      rgb(211,45,31) 50%
  );
}
.date {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}
.date .month {
  background: #a92419;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a92419;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #a92419;
}

.date .day {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#a92419;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.date .day::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 95%;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
}

.date .day::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Result](http://www.bootply.com/2fhjoLUKve)

Comment: sir the jumbotron is for the events not for the news. and i want the jumbotron the same size as that calendar icon :(

Comment: Ok then just provide a wireframe

Comment: can you send your jsfiddle herE? i dont have wireframe or js.

Comment: I'm about the scheme :) Just draw what you want to see as result